# Spring MVC multiple form backing object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Say, in request, I'm getting

```
?name=Jack&age=26&price=100&quantity=2
```

I have two model objects as below

```
public class User {

public String name;
public String age;

//getters and setters

}

public class Order {

public int price;
public int quantity;

//getters and setters

}
```

Now I want to have a controller method as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @ModelAttribute("order") Order order, Model model) {
    //stuff
}
```

As you can see I want to populate the model objects using two separate @ModelAttribute annotation. Is this possible in spring mvc?

Comment: Yea, It's possible in spring.

Answer (score 0):

Sattyaki, I suggest you to provide a few getters/setters to User and Order, and then compose the desired request with another class:

```
public class Checkout {

    private User user;
    private Order order;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

And to request for this operation, just issue a GET to the wanted URI(/submit) with your parameters. Observe that they are now using dot notation:

```
/submit?user.name=Jack&user.age=26&order.price=100&order.quantity=2
```

Comment: Can I do this without this `Checkout` wrapper class. Can I directly bind the request params to User and Order?

Comment: Providing correct getters and setters may work the way you want. 

But models with equal attribute names may get double written on you objects.

Comment: Can we control the binding between request parameters and model objects? Like only `name` and `age` will be bound to `student` and only `price` and `quantity` will be bound to `order`?